# How to use simulate.merMod() function with a GAMM object/how to do a parametric bootstrap with GAMM

Tags: r, simulation, lme4, gam

I am trying to carry out a parametric bootstrapping procedure for estimating the CI of random effect repeatability (ICC) in a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM, from the gamm4 package). The problem is, I can't figure out how to do so without using the `simulate.merMod()` function embedded in lme4, and this function seems not to work with the `mer` object produced by gamm4.

Here's some example data:

```
a <- seq(1, 2, length.out = 1000)
b <- 2*a^2.5 + 3
eta <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
socialGroup <- sort(rep(c(1:20), 1000/20))

data <- data.frame(resp = a, independent = b + eta, socialGroup = socialGroup)

mod <- gamm4(resp ~ s(independent) , 
             data = data,
             random = ~ (1|socialGroup))

lme4:::simulate.merMod(mod$mer, nsim = 10)
```

That last command should in theory work, but instead I get:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  random effects specified in re.form that were not present in original model
```

I've tried going through the source code for `simulate.merMod`, but I'm afraid it's beyond my knowledge. I have two questions:

a) If possible, how can I get the `simulate()` command to work for this object?
b) If anyone can provide guidance on how to do a parametric bootstrapping procedure with a GAMM object, that would be an enormous help.